# Clurdera cannot find class 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.solr.SolrStorageHandler'

Tags: solr, hive, cloudera, oozie

I'm using SolrStorageHandler to insert data into Solr from Hive tables.

I'm following [this](http://101.251.213.60:7180/static/help/topics/search_use_solrstoragehandler.html) tutorial but when lunching oozie workflow i get an error 
"Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Cannot find class 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.solr.SolrStorageHandler' (state=42000,code=40000)".

I cannot find SolrStorageHandler.jar on the web to add it manually to hive script. I'm doing something wrong or is this approach deprecated? If it's depracted how can I insert data to Solr from Hive in efficient way?

btw. Cloudera version is 5.4.3

Comment: link is pointing to "Using SolrStorageHandler (CDH 5.2 or later only)"  so there should not be any problem..  how are you packing and deploying your jar? is it through maven ? if so what is artifact for that ?

Comment: it should be hive-solr-handlerxxx.jar can you search in your cluster lib?

Comment: after that goto your cluster lib location and do jar -tvf <hive-solr-handlerxxx.jar> | grep -i solrstorage...  in the listing SolrStorageHandler class should present

Comment: I got this info from https://github.com/amitjaspal/solr-storagehandler/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: any clue till now ?